# Lagrangian density for a free EM field

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge

I wanted to derive the Lagrangian density of a free EM field $\mathcal{L}$ in the Lorenz gauge as:

$$
\mathcal{L} =- \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} A_{\mu} \partial^2 (g^{\mu \nu}- \partial^{\mu} \partial^{\nu}/\partial^2) A_{\nu} = \frac{1}{2} A_{\mu}^T \partial^2 g^{\mu \nu} A_{\nu}^T\tag{3.23}
$$

as on the p. 130 of Pokorski *Gauge Field Theories* book, Eq. (3.23). However, what I achieved differs in sign and I have no idea on how to obtain the transverse $A_{\mu}^T$ component in the equation above.

Comment: I have the same question, If you have answer to this question now, then please write it @Anne